# Multipart PUT/POST timeout

Tags: nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I configured my gitlab instance with an external nginx server according [this documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md) and following [nginx configuration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab).
All is working fine, but when i try to change some profile settings in the UI I get an connection reset.

The problem only occurs on multipart form POST/PUT operations.

The funny thing is, that there are no log entries in any gitlab log files, so i think there is a problem in the nginx configuration somewhere.

Please when someone has any idea on how to further analyse the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the MTU setting for the TCP-IP Stack on my windows machine. I switched from 1500 to 1300 and now all is working fine again.